# How to filter a table based on attributes a column using ActiveRecords Scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rails-activerecord, backend

I am trying to setup a Rails API backend for a bookstore project, and the frontend will be react. The backend has only one model for now which is the Book model. In the at the frontend I will like to filter the books based on their category. I want to setup the filtering at the backend so that when I select a dropdown at the frontend, only books that fit a particular category will be displayed. So far here is what I have at the backend:

**Book model**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, :category, presence: true

  scope :categorized, -> (category) { where("category LIKE ?",  "#{category}" ) }

end
```

my book controller looks like this:

**Book controller**

```
class Api::V1::BooksController < Api::V1::ApiController
   before_action :set_book, only: %i[show update destroy]

   def index
     @books = Book.all
     render json: @books
   end

   def categorized
     @category = params[:book]
     @books = Book.categorized(@category)
     render json: @books
   end

   def show
     render json: @book
   end

  def create
     @book = Book.new(book_params)

     if @book.save
       render json: @book, status: :created
     else
       render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
     end
  end

  def update
    if @book.update(book_params)
       render json: @book
    else
       render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
     @book.destroy
  end

  private

  def set_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :category)
  end
```

end

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :books do
      collection do
        get :categorized
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end

**Sample Data**

Here is a sample data I get from the API when I query for all books in the database:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings",
    "category": "Fable"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "His Dark Materials",
    "category": "Speech"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "To Say Nothing of the Dog",
    "category": "Fable"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "An Acceptable Time",
    "category": "Science fiction"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "A Scanner Darkly",
    "category": "Suspense/Thriller"
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "title": "The Golden Bowl",
    "category": "Science fiction"
}
]
```

My interest is I want to see only "Science fiction" books or any other category I choose only 
   using scopes. The categories are not limited to what is shown in the sample data; infact they 
   are likely to increase. The configuration I have above in the model is not getting what I 
   need. When I use postman, I do not get any result. The best I get is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

> scope :categorized, -> (category) { where("category LIKE ?",  "#{category}" ) }

Are you sure you need this scope for only one place?
Why don’t just filter in controller?
Second thought is using Book.where(category: category) which will produce “WHERE CATEGORY = ?” instead of “WHERE category LIKE”
Third - may be you can get rid of categorized route and just use index with optional param? You can also add pagination later in index controller - where...page(page).per(per)
Fourth, there is a good practice of using instance variable accessor methods instead of variable itself:

> def set_book
>       @book = Book.find(params[:id])
>     end

To

> def book
>       @book ||= Book.find(params[:id])
>     end

Also find method raises exception. You might want to rescue from it on class level. You can also use book.update! And book.save! in other methods and rescue from them as well - then you won’t need those if/else branches.

Comment: Hi Victor, If I'm to set up the filter in the controller, how do I go about it? Also, understand that the filter will not be for one value, instead it fill apply whenever there is a different category. it's easier to setup for a column with attributes that are only TRUE or FALSE but in this instance it's a bit tricky.